# comment form args are not translatable (customized comment form)

Tags: theme-development, translation, comment-form

I customized the comment form by changing the 'args'.

Short Example:

```
$comments_args = array(
    'title_reply'          => esc_html__( 'Leave a comment', 'mytheme' ),
    'title_reply_to'       => esc_html__( 'Leave a Comment to %s', 'mytheme' ),
    'cancel_reply_link'    => esc_html__( 'Cancel Reply', 'mytheme' ),
    'label_submit'         => esc_html__( 'Post Comment', 'mytheme' )
);
comment_form( $comments_args );
```

This works as expected, but the translation of these 'words' are not working and I don't get why.  All my other textes/words are translated fine but it will not take the translation of these words from the 'comments_args'.  I have the same issue for the 'comment_form_default_fields' filter.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please show a line of code which works, to compare.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for.  It does not work and would like to have a code that works.